# How do we get statistics from a continuous ping in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, ping, powershell-ise

In Windows command prompt, when you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> out of a continuous ping, the terminal will display the statistics:

```
Ping statistics for ::1:
    Packets: Sent = 6, Received = 6, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
Control-C
^C
```

In PowerShell (v4), the ping statistics aren't there if you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to break out of it. How do get around this?

Comment: As you found the answer to your own question, could you please create a real answer post and mark it as resolved ? This will help for future searches. Thanks.

Comment: What command did you type into PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it was because I was using PowerShell ISE.

There is a difference in the way vanilla PowerShell and [PowerShell ISE handle console input](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/02/04/console-application-non-support-in-the-ise.aspx).

If you want control-breaks to work the way they do in command prompt, you'll need to use vanilla PowerShell.